# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' Unresolved reference: embedding

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

I just opened my project and its getting me this error out of nowhere  have checked activity in
its problem from the line up there  cant find any solution for it any help please !
have tried creating a new project and copying all the files also same error and  have tried flutter clean , flutter build .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKzAO.png

Answer (score 0):

try this on android studio => `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`